# apply formatting filter dynamically in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, filter

**My goal is to apply a formatting filter that is set as a property of the looped object.**

Taking this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "value": "test value with null formatter",
    "formatter": null,
  },
  {
    "value": "uppercase text",
    "formatter": "uppercase",
  },
  {
    "value": "2014-01-01",
    "formatter": "date",
  }
]
```

The template code i'm trying to write is this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in list">
    {{ row.value | row.formatter }}
</div>
```

And i'm **expecting to see this result**:

```
test value with null formatter
UPPERCASE TEXT
Jan 1, 2014
```

But maybe obviusly this code throws an error:

```
Unknown provider: row.formatterFilterProvider <- row.formatterFilter
```

I can't immagine how to parse the "formatter" parameter inside the {{ }}; can anyone help me?

See the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/YnCR123dRQRqm3owQLcs?p=preview

Comment: I'm sorry maybe my post isn't clear: i don't need to *filter* the array. I need to **format the "value" string based on "formater" property**.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `|` is an angular construct that finds a defined filter with that name and applies it to the value on the left.  What I think you need to do is create a filter that takes a filter *name* as an argument, then calls the appropriate filter [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/PxX9U/1/) (adapted from M59's code):

***HTML:***

```
<div ng-repeat="row in list">
    {{ row.value | picker:row.formatter }}
</div>
```

***Javascript:***

```
app.filter('picker', function($filter) {
  return function(value, filterName) {
    return $filter(filterName)(value);
  };
});
```

Thanks to @karlgold's comment, here's a version that supports arguments.  The first example uses the `add` filter directly to add numbers to an existing number and the second uses the `useFilter` filter to select the `add` filter by string and pass arguments to it [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/31qgzfvk/1/):

***HTML:***

```
<p>2 + 3 + 5 = {{ 2 | add:3:5 }}</p>
<p>7 + 9 + 11 = {{ 7 | useFilter:'add':9:11 }}</p>
```

***Javascript:***

```
app.filter('useFilter', function($filter) {
    return function() {
        var filterName = [].splice.call(arguments, 1, 1)[0];
        return $filter(filterName).apply(null, arguments);
    };
});
```

Comment: Good idea! Strange to me that this doesn't exist already in the Angular core.

Comment: I think for now this is the best approach, more elegant than m59's one - that is also working of course. As you say, the "row.formatter" is a string, and should instead be a function name to get the code working; if there is no solution to get it parsed as a function, this seems the only workaround. Thank-you all!

Comment: Slightly fancier version of this that supports arguments to the filter spec (such as date format or number of decimal places):

http://plnkr.co/edit/tCPMjl?p=preview

Comment: And adding ` || "filter"` to the end of the line beginning `var filterName` handles the situation where no filter is defined.

Comment: Nice idea. Works 4.0. I'll add my implementation below, but credit here first.

Comment: Highly recommend kargold's solution, because Jason's updated version with arguments would make the filter no more dynamic, right?

Comment: TO avoid exceptions, the return statement can be as follows:
return filterName ? $filter(filterName)(value) : value;

Comment: @karlgold / @Jason Goemaat could you explein to me why did you use `var filterName = [].splice.call(arguments, 1, 1)[0];` instead of `var filterName = arguments[1];`

Comment: That removes `filterName` from the `arguments` array so the rest of the arguments can be passed to the filter call in the next line.

Answer (score 13):

I like the concept behind these answers, but don't think they provide the most flexible possible solution.

What I really wanted to do and I'm sure some readers will feel the same, is to be able to dynamically pass a filter expression, which would then evaluate and return the appropriate result.

So a single custom filter would be able to process all of the following:

`{{ammount | picker:'currency:"$":0'}}`

`{{date | picker:'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"'}}`

`{{name | picker:'salutation:"Hello"'}}` //Apply another custom filter

I came up with the following piece of code, which utilizes the `$interpolate` service into my custom filter. See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michiganfootball20/kjzz56zv/):

**Javascript**

```
myApp.filter('picker', function($interpolate ){
    return function(item,name){
       var result = $interpolate('{{value | ' + arguments[1] + '}}');
       return result({value:arguments[0]});
    };
});
```

Comment: This is the answer that served my purpose. I would just add a return with the item, in case there is no filter name. The point of this is to be as dynamic as possible. But thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One way to make it work is to use a function for the binding and do the filtering within that function. This may not be the best approach: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/acOdUsum/1/edit)**

```
<div ng-repeat="row in list">
  {{ foo(row.value, row.filter) }}
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.list = [
  {"value": "uppercase text", "filter": "uppercase"}
];
$scope.foo = function(value, filter) {
  return $filter(filter)(value);
};
```

Comment: Well thanks, but this isn't what i'm looking for. I'd like to format the "value" string giving as a formatter the "filter" value. Please take a look at the plunkr.

Comment: @user3259152 I updated with a solution. I'll keep investigating this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different need and so modified the above answer a bit (the `$interpolate` solution hits the same goal but is still limited):

```
angular.module("myApp").filter("meta", function($filter)
{
    return function()
    {
        var filterName = [].splice.call(arguments, 1, 1)[0] || "filter";
        var filter = filterName.split(":");
        if (filter.length > 1)
        {
            filterName = filter[0];
            for (var i = 1, k = filter.length; i < k; i++)
            {
                [].push.call(arguments, filter[i]);
            }
        }
        return $filter(filterName).apply(null, arguments);
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{ column.fakeData | meta:column.filter }}</td>
```

Data:

```
        {
            label:"Column head",
            description:"The label used for a column",
            filter:"percentage:2:true",
            fakeData:-4.769796600014472
        }
```

(`percentage` is a custom filter that builds off `number`)

Answer (score 0):

Credit in this post to Jason Goemaat.

Here is how I used it.

```
$scope.table.columns = [{ name: "June 1 2015", filter: "date" },
                        { name: "Name", filter: null },
                       ] etc...

<td class="table-row" ng-repeat="column in table.columns">
  {{ column.name | applyFilter:column.filter }}
</td>

app.filter('applyFilter', [ '$filter', function( $filter ) {
  return function ( value, filterName ) {
    if( !filterName ){ return value; } // In case no filter, as in NULL.
    return $filter( filterName )( value );
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved @Jason Goemaat's answer a bit by adding a check if the filter exists, and if not return the first argument by default:

```
.filter('useFilter', function ($filter, $injector) {
    return function () {
        var filterName = [].splice.call(arguments, 1, 1)[0];
        return $injector.has(filterName + 'Filter') ? $filter(filterName).apply(null, arguments) : arguments[0];
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of ng-table allows for dynamic table creation (ng-dynamic-table) based on a column configuration. Formatting a date field is as easy as adding the format to your field value in your columns array.

Given

```
{
    "name": "Test code",
    "dateInfo": {
        "createDate": 1453480399313
        "updateDate": 1453480399313
    }
}

columns = [
    {field: 'object.name', title: 'Name', sortable: 'name', filter: {name: 'text'}, show: true},
    {field: "object.dateInfo.createDate | date :'MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss a'", title: 'Create Date', sortable: 'object.dateInfo.createDate', show: true}
]

<table ng-table-dynamic="controller.ngTableObject with controller.columns" show-filter="true" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td ng-repeat="column in $columns">{{ $eval(column.field, { object: row }) }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something a bit more crude, but less involving:

**HTML:**

Use the ternary operator to check if there is a filter defined for the row:

```
ng-bind="::data {{row.filter ? '|' + row.filter : ''}}"
```

**JS:**

In the data array in Javascript add the filter:

```
, {
        data: 10,
        rowName: "Price",
        months: [],
        tooltip: "Price in DKK",
        filter: "currency:undefined:0"
    }, {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use (Angular Version 1.3.0-beta.8 accidental-haiku).

This filter allows you to use filters with or without filter options.

**applyFilter** will check if the filter exists in Angular, if the filter does not exist, then an error message with the filter name will be in the browser console like so...

> **The following filter does not exist: greenBananas**

When using *ng-repeat*, some of the values will be undefined. **applyFilter** will handle these issues with a soft fail.

```
app.filter( 'applyFilter', ['$filter', '$injector', function($filter, $injector){

  var filterError = "The following filter does not exist: ";

  return function(value, filterName, options){

    if(noFilterProvided(filterName)){ return value; }
    if(filterDoesNotExistInAngular(filterName)){ console.error(filterError + "\"" + filterName + "\""); return value; }
    return $filter(filterName)(value, applyOptions(options));
  };

  function noFilterProvided(filterName){
    return !filterName || typeof filterName !== "string" || !filterName.trim();
  }

  function filterDoesNotExistInAngular(filterName){
    return !$injector.has(filterName + "Filter");
  }

  function applyOptions(options){
    if(!options){ return undefined; }
    return options;
  }
}]);
```

Then you use what ever filter you want, which may or may not have options.

```
// Where, item => { name: "Jello", filter: {name: "capitalize", options: null }}; 
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{ item.name | applyFilter:item.filter.name:item.filter.options }}
</div>
```

Or you could use with separate data structures when building a table.

```
// Where row => { color: "blue" };
// column => { name: "color", filter: { name: "capitalize", options: "whatever filter accepts"}};
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
    {{ row[column.name] | applyFilter:column.filter.name:column.filter.options }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you find that you require to pass in more specific values you can add more arguments like this...

```
// In applyFilter, replace this line
return function(value, filterName, options){
// with this line
return function(value, filterName, options, newData){

// and also replace this line
return $filter(filterName)(value, applyOptions(options));
// with this line
return $filter(filterName)(value, applyOptions(options), newData);
```

Then in your HTML perhaps your filter also requires a key from the **row** object

```
// Where row => { color: "blue", addThisToo: "My Favorite Color" };
// column => { name: "color", filter: { name: "capitalize", options: "whatever filter accepts"}};
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
    {{ row[column.name] | applyFilter:column.filter.name:column.filter.options:row.addThisToo }}
  </td>
</tr>
```