# dynamic filters in Angularjs with error checking included

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, service, filter

I am would like to apply dynamic filters like this, but also check whether the filter exists first to handle any errors.

```
<td ng-repeat="row in table.row>
  {{ row[ column.row.dataKey ] | column.row.dynamicFilterName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with after some research, hope this helps...

> **Note:** column.row.filter === 'myFilterName'; // no $ proceeds the string.

```
<td ng-repeat="row in table.row>
  {{ row[ column.row.dataKey ] | applyFilter: column.row.filter }}
</td>
```

> **Note:** applyFilter is an actual filter that will apply other filters. Found this solution here on Stack: [dynamic filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491747/apply-formatting-filter-dynamically-in-a-ng-repeat)

```
app.filter( 'applyFilter', [ '$filter', '$injector', function( $filter, $injector ){

  var filterError = "The following filter does not exist: ";

  return function ( value, filterName ){

   // Just return the value if no filtername provided.
    if( !filterName ){ return value; }

    // Below checks the filter name in the injector as "filterNameFilter"
    // then spits out a soft error and just returns the value if 
    // no filter exists.

    if( !$injector.has( filterName + "Filter" )){ console.error( filterError + filterName ); return value; }

    // if there is a string name that exists as a filter, then apply it.
    return $filter( filterName )( value );
  };
}]);
```