# Specifying a custom filter for a directive as a scope property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I suspect I'm overlooking something profoundly obvious.

I am trying to use a custom filter in a directive. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1...s-in-angularjs, I should be able to do so by injecting my directive with $filter, and then in the template fetching my custom filter via filter:givenFilterName.

However, I cannot get this to work. I can *directly* use my custom filter, but I really want to be able to specify which filter to use as a value for the directive.

jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/kulihi/3/edit?html,js,output

EDIT: In response to the possible duplicate, the picker solution does not appear to work within the context of a directive template.

jsbin example with the filter picker included: http://jsbin.com/kulihi/7/edit?html,js,output

EDIT 2: I'm dumb; mis-read the order of the arguements on the picker filter.  It works better when you read the answer completely.  Thanks muchly!

http://jsbin.com/kulihi/8/watch?html,js,output

Comment: possible duplicate of [apply formatting filter dynamically in a ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491747/apply-formatting-filter-dynamically-in-a-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom filter as: `$filter('yourfiltername')(source, arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Not from within the template itself you can't, and I would prefer to not have to pre-filter those contents if possible.