# Can I pass filter to html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have multiple fields in table that I am displaying simply with ng-repeat, but the need to format them occurred, is there some way to pass filter from scope to html?
Below code doesn't work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in array">
     <td>{{info.key}}</td>
     <td class="table-detail-panels">{{ info.value | info.filter }}</td>
</tr>
```

aslo dont know if I should pass string or filter object

```
info.filter = 'date' // or
info.filter = $filter('date')
```

EDIT1: `info.filter` is a variable, it can have different filters, not only `'date'`.

EDIT2: It is possibly worth to mention that `ng-repeat` is inside directive/controll that im building. And purpose of this controll is to being able to display everything that exist on this world in a sensible way, thats why I need filters. Or easy way of adding them to controll.

ANSWER:
After browsing a while I found answer on stack: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491747/apply-formatting-filter-dynamically-in-a-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm understanding, you want to filter a value in the array differently based off some conditions. If so, I'd recommend using the filter inside your controller and then repeating in HTML preformatted. And use ng-bind-HTML with ngsanitize if needed:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'customFilter1', 'customFilter2',
    function ($scope, custom1, custom2) {

        // however you are creating your array - do the logic here
        if(something) {
           $scope.variable = custom1(arg)
        } else {
           $scope.variable = custom2(arg)
        }


     }
])
```

** This is the general idea, obviously it will not work exactly like written above. I use the same idea often when I'm not 100% sure what data will be passed and want to format strings, numbers differently.

Comment: Thought about that, however controller is now responsible for formatting data not veiw and that breaks some principles and stuff :P And peolpe generally dont like that. Not to mention big if constructs.

Comment: Within the constraints of a best practices, you could move the business logic into a service. And if you have a lot of conditionals this makes a lot of sense too.

Answer (score 0):

Angular already has that built-in. Just use something like :

```
<td class="table-details-panels">{{info.value | date: 'dd-MM-yyy'}}</td>
```

If you only want to filter some `td`'s :

```
<td ng-if="needsToBeFilteredCondition" class="table-details-panels">{{info.value | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
<td ng-if="!needsToBeFilteredCondition" class="table-details-panels">{{info.value}}</td>
```

Comment: The thing is I dont want to attach same filter to all fields from table, I will add more code to clarify