# Bind filter in angularjs template

Tags: angularjs

I know it is possible to bind the filter expression in a template to a variable in your model. Is is also possible to change the filter itself based on viewmodel data?

Imagine the following line (e.g. inside of ngRepeat):

```
{{ item.name | item.filter:item:filterParams }}
```

---

Edit:

The idea is to have different filters applied to the template depending on the value of `item.filter`. Is it possible to switch the entire filter (e.g. `date`, `filter`) not just it's arguments based on a variable and how would that have to be defined?

Comment: don't understand what you want?

Comment: @PankajParkar I updated my question. Hopefully my point becomes clearer now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491747/apply-formatting-filter-dynamically-in-a-ng-repeat