# Angular directive to apply any filter as an ngModel parser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-filters

This may be difficult to explain so I'll do so with code.

I'm trying to create a directive which will take any angular filter and apply it as an ng-model parser on an input. E.g.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="app.name" model-filter="lowercase" />
```

would take anything typed into the input and apply Angular's lowercase filter before placing it on the model.

**view: "DaViD" - model: "david"**

Another example would be a customer filter which trims whitespace from an input.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="app.name" model-filter="trim" />
```

**view: " hello " - model: "hello"**

Here is my best shot at creating the directive.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('modelFilter', function($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {

      var filter = $attrs.modelFilter;

      $ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {

        value = $filter(filter);

        return value

      });


    }
  };
});
```

Here is a plunkr of what I have so far.

https://plnkr.co/edit/c04LW3XZHXIU0HXccgP5?p=preview

Aside from the fact that this doesn't work, it needs to fulfil two other functions

1) It needs to work with any filters, even ones that are chained together and has arguments, so I'm not sure how to take the whole contents of the attribute and run all filters chained within it.

2) Ideally, any validators would run afterwards. For example, if I had a filter for removing alpha characters in a price field so that the user could type "$4.00" and the model would contain "4.00" then it would need to validate as a number. Not sure if things are done in the right order to make that work.

Comment: What do you mean by this: *"It needs to work with any filters"*? If I put `model-filter="xx"`, it should work also? How will you check what is a valid/invalid filter?

Comment: What I mean is that if I use the following in a view {{price | currency : 'USD' | filter2 | filter3}} the it will just work because angular understands filter arguments and chaining. So, if I use my directive like this - <input ng-model="app.price" model-filter="currency : 'USD' | filter2 | filter3" /> then I would like it to work as expected, if possible.

Comment: Well, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491747/apply-formatting-filter-dynamically-in-a-ng-repeat

Comment: I think that question contains everything I need to accomplish what I want but my Angular still isn't that great so I'm not sure. I think what I might need to do is split the attribute down into separate filters then loop through them and apply them one at a time to the previous result. I think I have to split the arguments in each one and apply them manually as in the first answer, but the second answer with the $interpolate also looks interesting.